# Using AWS CLI from Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, aws-cli

I'm trying to use AWS cli within a `script` section of an Azure pipeline. The script section is in a template file and it's accessed from the main pipeline.

```
steps:
- bash: |
    step_function_state=`aws stepfunctions list-executions --state-machine-arn $(stateMachineArn) --status-filter RUNNING |  jq -r '.executions[]|.status' | head -1`
    echo "State machine RUNNING status: ${step_function_state}"
    # Rest of the script#
  displayName: "Test Script"
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $(AWS_DEFAULT_REGION)
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

`stateMachineArn`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` are stored in a variable group. When running the pipeline it gives the following error,

> An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the ListExecutions operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Using the same credentials I am able to run my local CLI and get the results.
I tried `printenv` command and all the AWS variables are in the environment too. What could I possibly do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that this issue occurred due to credential mismatch.
After adding the correct credentials (same as local cli) the pipeline CLI also started to work.
Based on the error log it felt like `aws_session_token` could be an issue but the actual issue was in `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`.